# White space at end of webpage, IE and Chrome show it in a different place?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Hey all I posted a question earlier here : [Why am I getting white space between my HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460319/why-am-i-getting-white-space-between-my-html-element) which was solved.

I have continued working on this page and have ended up with the following:

IE Screenshot:

http://postimage.org/image/2aqd5k99g/

Chrome Screenshot:

http://postimage.org/image/1xdm95138/

What I really want is basically the chrome screenshot but without the white space below my red footer. What can I do to get this desired effect for both IE and Chrome?

My HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="swaggersstyle.css">
        <title>Oamaru Backpackers Hostel, Swaggers Backpackers - Home</title>

</head>


<body>
    <img src="final.jpg" id="banner"></img>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="links"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="links"><a href="planning.html">Planning</a></li>
        <li class="links"><a href="construction.html">Construction</a></li>
        <li class="links"><a href="evaluation.html">Evaluation</a></li>
    </ul>


<div id="mainc">
    <p>Make Yourself at Home</p>
<p>Swaggers Backpackers is a converted old house located within walking distance of all the best parts of Oamaru. Explore the old victorian era buildings and shops of the city centre, or see the penguin colonies down the street. Swaggers is owned and operated by camp mum Agra, who makes all guests feel welcome, informed, and perhaps a bit mothered. </p>
</div>   

<div id="rightcolumn">
<p>hghadgadgadg</p>
<p>easfasf</p>
<p>safSFS</p>
<p>afafafadf</p>
<p>safasf</p>
<p>saasfasf</p>
<p>fasfsaf</p>
</div>

<div id ="footer">
<p> fsafasfasf </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS file is:

```
html{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color:#464E54;
}

body{
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid black;
}

#banner{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}

#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;

}

#mainc {
    float: left;
    width: 760px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
}

#rightcolumn {
    padding-left: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #dad8bf;
    width: 197px;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: red;
}

.links {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
}

a:link {

    display: block;
    width: 232px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444444;
    background-color: #dad8bf;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

a:visited {

    display: block;
    width: 232px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444444;
    background-color: #dad8bf;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 0px;
}


a:hover {
    background-color: #999999;
}

a:active{
    background-color: #999999;
}
```

Once again cheers for everyones help - hopefully after this I will be a bit more familiar to these mysterious white lines showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following rule

```
 div#footer p {
     margin:0;
 }
```

Comment: hmmm I added that and saved, there didnt seem to be any changes in either of the browsers - could it be the padding of a different element? cheers for the reply.

Comment: did you check the fiddle? white space isn't displaying there.

Comment: yep thats strange I dont see why its not showing up on my page when I add the padding = 0; property... hmm

Comment: i have updated the post. Now i checked in both chrome and IE9 and it's rendering alright.

Answer (score 1):

Use inspect element on chrome by right clicking.
you will find the area which is blue by moving mouse over the respected area and then you can solve the problem

Have you checked it  on different chrome browsers (From different PCs chrome browsers) or do you have any download manager extension installed on your browser, if yes; then disable that first and then reload your page.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Many of these problems are solved, only by importing and using a [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). Why don't you use them?

Theory: Browsers apply some default style on HTML elements, and they are not the same in that. For example, IE might add `15px` margin to `p` elements, while Chrome might add `13px`. This means that incosistencies can exist between default styles of HTML elements across browsers. CSS Reset is technically a set of CSS rules which zero-outs these default values. For example,  you can see that in CSS reset, a `p` is directed to have `0` margin.

```
p
{
    margin: 0;
}
```